# Bitbucket - Can I track or see who clones or pulls from the repository?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-clone

Does Bitbucket keep a log of who clones or updates their local repository, and not just commits? Is it possible to access this information? 
It would be useful for me to see which team members have cloned or pulled, so I can know for sure that they did what they were supposed to do and did it properly. 
Thanks

Comment: Update: no update. This request is still open (6/12/2019) [https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/8322](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/8322)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this currently available now. But there's open request for this functionality.

https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/8322

Answer (score 3):

The feature seems to be under consideration https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/8322/add-clones-and-pushes-to-audit-logging-bb

But right now such logs are not available. There are audit logs available and those may be enhanced in future to provide clone logs etc.
https://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/08/15/new-audit-logs-give-you-the-who-what-when-and-where/ but they are more

Comment: Are those Audit Logs mentioned in the blog post still available? I could not find them on bitbucket.org account